# Unable to run shopt rm -rf from ruby script

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script which needs to run `bash builtin command - shopt` to remove all the files and folders except few of them. Below is the piece of code where I am facing the problem.

```
class Test1
     def initialize(hostname, user, password)
        begin

                    @hostname = hostname
                    @username = user
                    @password = password

                    @ssh = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password)

                    @rm_cmd = "shopt -s extglob; rm -rf !(file1.zip|dir1|dir2|dir3)"

                    cmd = @ssh.exec!(@rm_cmd)

        puts "#{cmd}"


        rescue => e
                puts e
        end 
   end
end


#initailizing the object
Test1.new("ABC", "user1", pass1")
```

It is able to establish the connection to the server but looks like it is failing to execute `@rm_cmd` which is not caught by the `rescue` block. `puts "#{cmd}"` prints the following error message:

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `shopt -s extglob; rm -rf !((file1.zip|dir1|dir2|dir3)'
```

I tried to give the escape character  before parenthesis i.e., `shopt -s extglob; rm -rf !\(file1.zip|dir1|dir2|dir3\)` but it dint work either. Can someone help me in more debugging and making this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to escape command use `shellwords` extension from Ruby Standard Library and specify `extglob` as bash options (it is better because remote user can have other shell):

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'shellwords'

ssh = Net::SSH.start('remote-server', 'user', password: 'password')

command = Shellwords.escape('ls !(Projects|Downloads)')
p ssh.exec!(%Q{/bin/bash -O extglob -c #{command}})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. That exactly meets my need. But I have a question - when I tried to run `ssh.exec!("{/bin/bash -O extglob -c #{command}}")` it gave the following error message `"bash: {/bin/bash: No such file or directory\n"`. Can you please explain why does it take `%Q` but not the `double quotes`?

Comment: Read about [% notation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation). So, in your case the command should be: ssh.exec!("/bin/bash -O extglob -c #{command}")